# Identical SEs for all slopes in a regression on a factor

Tags: r, regression, anova, standard-error, lm

I'm relatively new to R and stats, and I just encountered a situation that I haven't before. I ran an lm (in R) with species richness as the response variable and elevation level (I have five of them ranging from 3000 m to 5000 m; it's a categorical variable) as the predictor. The model output gives me the exact same values for standard errors for all the slopes (0.7709 for the intercept, and 1.0903 for the other 4 elevations).  I believe data that would give a similar output is fairly easy to generate (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611798/r-identical-se-values-for-all-slopes-in-an-lm).  However, when I calculate SEs for my data directly, I get different values for each elevation.  Could someone help me understand what is going on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is not described clearly enough to be 100% sure, but given that linear regression assumes constant variance, if you have equal numbers in each group, for a simple model you would expect the estimated coefficients to have the same standard error.

The individual group sample standard deviations would be unequal but the combined estimate of the standard deviation is used for them all.

So for a one-way ANOVA-type model `y~elevationlevel`, $s^2=\frac{\sum_i r_i^2}{n-g}$ where $r_i$ is the $i$th residual, and $g$ is the number of groups, and the slope-coefficient variances will be a scaled version of that estimate.

Since the variance is assumed to be constant, this combined estimate of the variance is used. It's a kind of weighted average of the individual group variances. With equal group size it's in fact a direct average of the individual variances.